# Matrix power by Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, svd

The singular Value Decomposition of a square matrix A is `A = U*S*V.T`.

We can take the n'th power of A as follows: `A^3= U*S^3*V.T`

Below is some basic python code where I am applying this.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
A_3rd = np.linalg.matrix_power(A,3)
assert np.array_equal(A_3rd,  np.dot(A, np.dot(A,A))  )

# svd for A
U,s,V = np.linalg.svd(A)
S = np.zeros(A.shape); S[:2,:2]= np.diag(s) # fill diagonals
S = np.asmatrix(S) # convert from array to matrix
print U.shape, S.shape, V.shape # print shapes

A_3rd_by_SVD =np.dot(U, np.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(S, 3),V))
```

However I do not get the same value as numpy.linalg_matrix_power(). Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
>>A_3rd 
matrix([[ 37,  54],
        [ 81, 118]])
>>A_3rd_by_SVD
matrix([[  38.,   54.],
        [  86.,  122.]])
```

Comment: *"We can take the n'th power of A as follows: `A^3= U*S^3*V.T`"*  This is not correct. `V.T` is not the inverse of `U`.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser I don't understand why you thought that is my assumption. I am not treating it as such. U contains the eig vectors of A * A.T in its cols; V contains the eig vectors of A.T * A in its columns. Both V and U are orthonormal matrices. Hence inv(V) = V.T. And S has the square roots of eigen values of both.

Comment: How do your statements imply that `A^3 = U * S^3 * V.T`?  `A^3 = (U * S * V.T)^3`. How do you go from there to `U * S^3 * V.T`?

Comment: If `A` is *symmetric*, your calculation works, but in your example, `A` is not symmetric.

Comment: Oh, exactly! Thanks, I was just implementing this from memory (rather than deriving it) and omitted that small(!) detail of symmetry. Can you post this as your answer, and I will accept. Pity the fate of what started as a programming question...

Comment: Since the question is not really a programming question, perhaps it should simply be closed or deleted?

Comment: Fair enough, will requestthat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a linear algebra misunderstanding.